# I'd like to display the separated Forms and set initial values from Session with Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, session, shopping-cart

I’d like to implement a Shopping Cart (in logged-out status) like Amazon, Rakuten and so on with Django4.1.

So, I tried to write codes using Session, not using Database and ModelForm.

However, I am stuck and do not know how to do.

The Shopping Cart of Rakuten (https://www.rakuten.co.jp/) displays SelectBoxes for quantities and the number of SelectBoxes is same with that of species of Items after we add items to the cart.

And when I checked the HTML with developer tool, I found <select name=“units[0]”> and <select name=“units[1]”> in the Rakuten Cart.

I could display several Forms, for example CartForm, but all Forms showed <select name=“quality”> in HTML and they were not separated.

So, if I change one of the Form, for instance change a quantity to 30, the number of quantity of all Forms become 30.

I found these following pages, but it seems they cannot be the solution because they cannot change the “name” attribute dynamically.

・https://progl.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/07/23/185923

・https://www.appsloveworld.com/django/100/20/change-the-name-attribute-of-form-field-in-django-template-using

Besides, I’d like to push the initial numbers, quantities, which are gotten from Session to the each Forms, but I have no idea what to do (in my code, all quantity is 1).

I tried,

views.py

```py
cart_form = CartForm(initial=???)
```

forms.py

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['quantity'].initial = ???
```

But neither of the way could work.

What I want to implement are

- **I want to set each values of “quantity” stored in Session to each Form as the initial value.**
- **I want to display Forms separately(ex: a Form for item A and another Form for item B) or change “name” attributes(ex: a Form for <select name=“quantity_0”>,  another Form for <select name=“quantity_1”>)**

In the nutshell, the Shopping Cart like Amazon and Rakuten without logged-in.

I searched, most of the cases in Japanese, but sadly I could not find the solution.

Here's my codes (I omitted some parts having nothing to do with).

◆views.py

```
import uuid
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

# request.session data example
# {
#   ‘cart’: {‘4’: {'item_id': 4, 'quantity': 3, 'stored': 'no'},
#           '6': {'item_id': 6, 'quantity': 2, 'stored': 'no'},
#           '7': {'item_id': 7, 'quantity': 1, 'stored': 'no’}},
#   ‘cart_uuid’: UUID('4454d486-c676-414e-a4b8-5492d629f145’),
# }

@require_http_methods(['GET', 'POST'])
def cart_detail(request, uuid): 
    
    if "cart" not in request.session:
        initiate_shopping_session(request)

    if request.method == 'POST': 
        cart_form = CartForm(request.POST or None)
        if cart_form.is_valid():
            do_something()
            return redirect("shopping:cart_detail", uuid=uuid)
    else:
        cart_form = CartForm() # initialを入れるためには以下のforの中に入れる？

    cart = request.session.get("cart")
    item_ids = [int(c) for c in cart]
    added_items = ItemPhoto.objects.select_related('item').filter(item_id__in=item_ids).filter(priority=1)
    items = []
    total_price: int = 0 

    for added_item in added_items:
        quantity = request.session['cart'][str(added_item.item.pk)].get("quantity")
        item_dict = {
            'item_id': added_item.item.pk,
            'name': added_item.item.name,
            'photo': added_item.photo,
            'price': added_item.item.price,
            'quantity': quantity,
        }
        items.append(item_dict)

        total_price += added_item.item.price * quantity

    context = {
        'items': items, 
        'total_price': '{:,.0f}'.format(total_price), 
        'cart_form': cart_form,
    }
    return render(request, "shopping/cart_detail.html", context)
```

◆urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import re_path
from shopping import views
app_name = "shopping"

urlpatterns = [
    path("item_detail/<int:pk>/", views.item_detail, name="item_detail"), 
    path("cart/detail/<uuid:uuid>/", views.cart_detail, name="cart_detail"),
]
```

◆forms.py

```
from django import forms
choice_quantities = ((i, i) for i in range(1, 21))

class CartForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.ChoiceField(
        label=‘Quantity’,
        required=True,
        choices=choice_quantities,
        initial=1,
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['quantity'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'quantity_of_item’
```

◆cart_detail.html

```
{% block main %}
{% for item in items %}
<table class="">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <td>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {% for field in cart_form %}
            <div class="">{{ field }}</div>
            <button class="" type="submit">Change</button>
          {% endfor %}
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Python: 3.9
Django: 4.1

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did, but is it proper? Thanks.